# inner html should displace by the grid

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jqgrid

```
document.getElementById('add').innerHTML=http://localhost/www/easyui-crud-demo/index.html;
```

Hello above is the code i used in java script.when i clicked the button the div(id is 'add') should replace by the grid(index.html displays a grid). Is it correct ?  please help thanks

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ll say 'My God' :) , if you are thinking that from the inner HTML assignment you are expecting to load  the index.html page ?

If you are assigning the CONTENTS of the div by a LINK you need proper html anchor tag e.g

```
document.getElementById('add').innerHTML="<a href='http://localhost/www/easyui-crud-demo/index.html'>linkname </a>";
```

if you want to LOAD the contents , use AJAX or IFRAME

e.g [IFRAME](http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance)
    [AND](http://www.cryer.co.uk/resources/javascript/script4.htm)  to get you on track

hope this will help you.

forgive my words :)

Comment: The _innerHTML_ solution will only output a link that needs to be clicked (requires 2 clicks 1. Button click 2. Anchor click) and OP wants to show the grid with a single button click.